# Tensor product of a module and a localized ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity.
Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$.
Let $M$ be an $A$-module.
Let $x \in M$. Suppose $x\otimes 1 = 0$ in $M\otimes_A S^{-1}A$.
Then there exists $s \in S$ such that $sx = 0$.
The usual proof uses the fact that $M\otimes_A S^{-1}A$ is canonically isomorphic to $S^{-1}M$ as an $S^{-1}A$-module.
Can we prove it directly? In other words, can we prove it without using 
$S^{-1}M$?

Comment: I can think of ways to do it that don't involve using the fact that $M \otimes S^{-1}A$ is *isomorphic* to $S^{-1}M$ but they still use $S^{-1}M$ as a module.

Comment: No we cannot prove it directly. You need an explicit construction / realization of the tensor product in order to say something which goes beyond the definition of the tensor product as an object classifying bilinear maps. Also note that this is false for sheaves of modules - therefore the proof cannot be really formal as you might expect.

Comment: Some amplification: $x \otimes 1 = 0$ means that $\beta(x,1)=0$ for every $A$-bilinear map $\beta : M \times S^{-1} A \to T$, where $T$ is some $A$-module. But in order to use this, we have to really *choose* some $T$ and some $\beta$. Otherwise we cannot gain anything. And the canonical choice is, of course, to take $T=S^{-1} M$ with $\beta(m,\frac{a}{s})=\frac{am}{s}$. It then follows $\frac{x}{1}$ in $S^{-1} M$ and hence $sx=0$ for some $s \in S$. Perhaps this is what Jim meant? But I don't think that we can avoid $S^{-1} M$ (or something isomorphic and concrete as this localization).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I mean by "proving it directly" proving it without using the isomorphism.

Comment: On the other hand you can "cheat" somehow: Since everything here commutes with filtered colimits, wlog $S$ is finite, then wlog $S=\{1,f,f^2,\dotsc\}$. But then $S^{-1} A$ is the colimit of $A \xrightarrow{f} A \xrightarrow{f} \dotsc$, so that $M \otimes S^{-1} A$ is the colimit of $M \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{f} \dotsc$. From here the claim follows. I wouldn't call this direct, since again we actually find a more explicit realization of the tensor product.

Comment: A more basic question with the same lesson: If $m \otimes 1 = 0$ in $M \otimes_A A$, why do we have $m=0$? Is there a "direct" proof which doesn't use the isomorphism $M \otimes_A A \cong M$? Well, again as above, we have to apply the universal property to at least *some* bilinear map on $M \times A$. And one just chooses the obvious one $M \times A \to M$. But this almost the whole proof of $M \otimes_A A \cong M$ anyway.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yep that's what I mean, you can get it from the map into $S^{-1}M$ without knowing that that map is an iso.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't think it's a "cheat". We don't need to construct $S^{-1}M$ to prove it. The merit is more visible, for example, in the case $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cheating answer, assuming that you know that $M \otimes_A -$ preserves colimits (for example by adjunction) and $M \otimes_A A \cong M$:

We can write $S^{-1} A = \mathrm{colim}_{s \in S} A$, where we make $S$ into a directed category via $\hom(s,t) = \{r \in S : rs=t\}$ with transition maps $\hom(s,t) \to \hom(A,A)$ defined by $r \mapsto (a \mapsto ra)$. It follows $M \otimes S^{-1} A = \mathrm{colim}_{s \in S} M$ with the "same" transition maps. By the explicit construction of directed colimits, we conclude that $x \otimes 1 = 0$ iff there is some $s \in S$ with $sx=0$.

But in fact this argument is just another proof of $M \otimes_A S^{-1} A \cong S^{-1} M$.

Comment: "But in fact this argument is just another proof of $M \otimes_A S^{-1} A \cong S^{-1} M$."
Are you saying that giving another proof of a proposition is cheating? Anyway, please don't post an answer which you think cheating. That's rude.

Comment: I just wasn't sure what you mean by "direct proof".

Comment: I explained it in my comment to you. Anyway, please don't post an answer which you think cheating. That is rude.

Comment: You cannot really tell me what to do or not to do. I have answered your question. If you don't like it or it doesn't help, feel free to downvote it (I don't care at all). Perhaps others will find the answer helpful anyway.

Comment: Come on. Don't post an answer which you *think* is cheating.

Comment: Before you make clear the meaning of "direct proof" *every* answer will be cheating.

Comment: I *made* it clear in my comment to you.
Anyway, why bother posting a cheating answer?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg "Makoto" means sincere or truth in Japanese :). Maybe you should have said "Here is a cheeky answer".